# Css Sprite of SVG files

Tags: html, css, sprite

I am developing a template with html5, css3, js and jQuery.

I have some SVG photos and I was wondering if is it possible to make a sprite with all of them. I have rad on the internet a couple of articles on this topic but I didn't quite understand. I am very confused.

**Is this actually possible? If so, how do I do it ?**

**Can someone please clarify this for me ?**